# What is the word for when you are scared on someone else's behalf

Tags: single-word-requests

For instance, if you were running through a crowd and could not find someone, and you are scared for them, what is that word?

What could fill the blank:

He was running through the crowds, _________ as he tried to find her.

Comment: I would use *unnerved* but it doesn't match the dictionaries' definition : *make (someone) lose courage or confidence*, so no answer for you ;)

Comment: It appears that you are unfamiliar with the basic English word *worry* and its inflections.

Answer (score 1):

the English idiom **fear for** works nicely here.  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fear+for)

> fear for someone or something

As in:

> ... and you **fear for** them ...

Answer (score 0):

**frantically**

fran·ti·cal·ly  /ˈfran(t)iklē/ – [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=frantically+definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1)

> in a distraught way owing to fear, anxiety, or other emotion.

He ran *frantically* through the crowds as he tried to find her.